# Spring Boot2 Oauth2 Implicit Flow - http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize getting Access Denied

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have created a Spring Boot 2 Application, integrated SpringFox Swagger 2.8.0 with Implicit Oauth2 Grant for Authentication and Authorization.

The Code is working fine but when I click Authorize button it redirects to the

> http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=test-app-client-id&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fwebjars%2Fspringfox-swagger-ui%2Foauth2-redirect.html&scope=read&state=U3VuIE9jdCAxNCAyMDE4IDIwOjQyOjUwIEdNVCswNTMwIChJbmRpYSBTdGFuZGFyZCBUaW1lKQ%3D%3D

but shows Access Denied like as shown below.

My complete project is available in **[GitHub](https://github.com/AlexMan123/spring-boot2-oauth2-sample)**

**MainApplication.java**

```
@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@RestController
public class MainApplication /*extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter*/
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityConfiguration security() {
      return SecurityConfigurationBuilder.builder()//<19>
          .clientId("test-app-client-id")
          .build();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityScheme oauth() {
          List<GrantType> grantTypes = new ArrayList<>();
          ImplicitGrant implicitGrant = new ImplicitGrant(new LoginEndpoint("http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize"),"access_code");
          grantTypes.add(implicitGrant);
          List<AuthorizationScope> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
          scopes.add(new AuthorizationScope("read","Read access on the API"));
        return new OAuthBuilder()
                .name("SECURITY_SCHEME_OAUTH2")
                .grantTypes(grantTypes)
                .scopes(scopes)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket docket()
    {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(getClass().getPackage().getName()))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(oauth()))
            .apiInfo(generateApiInfo());
    }


    private ApiInfo generateApiInfo()
    {
        return new ApiInfo("Sample Service", "This service is to check Sample Service.", "Version 1.0",
            "Sample Service", "123@test.com", "Apache 2.0", "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0");
    }
}
```

[image]

### Update 1

I have added the security and the passwordencoder configure suggested from **@AlexanderPetrov**. Things are working fine, when I add `@EnableResourceServer` my login screen is showing **Full authentication is required to access this resource**  like as shown below

[image]

Can anyone please help me on this

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the following changes in your code

1. Form login configuration is necessary for implicit flow.
2. Also if we use implicit flow token will be generated through authorization url instead of token url. So you need to change "/oauth/token" to "oauth/authorize". configure method below

   ```
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated()
       .and()
       .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
       .and()
       .formLogin().permitAll()
       .and()
       .csrf().disable();
   }
   ```
3. Add password encoder in `SecurityConfig` class and invoke it to encode user password in `globalUserDetails` method. Encoder is necessary because you use in memory passwords. So without password encoder application fails with an error:

   ```
   Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
   ```

Code fragment below

```
@Autowired
public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder();
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()).
            withUser("bill").password(passwordEncoder.encode("abc123")).roles("ADMIN").and()
            .withUser("$2a$10$TT7USzDvMxMZvf0HUVh9p.er1GGnjNQzlcGivj8CivnaZf9edaz6C")
            .password("$2a$10$TT7USzDvMxMZvf0HUVh9p.er1GGnjNQzlcGivj8CivnaZf9edaz6C").roles("USER");
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Hope it helps. I've created branch for your project but couldn't push it because of 403. So all necessary code is here in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I just paste incorrect configure for HttpSecurity. I've edited my answer. Please check it again.

Comment: could you explain what did you mean "to hide the client_id display". If I understand you correctly you want to hide value of client_id ?

Comment: I have updated that but when I add `@EnableResourceServer` I am getting 401 for my login. Can you check my update

Comment: any idea on this

Answer (score 2):

When you enable a resource server, you need to configure the check_token URL, so that it can reach the OAuth2 authorization server and validate the given access_token.

You could do something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${oauth.url.internal}")    // e.g. http://localhost:8082/oauth
    private String oauthUrl;

    @Value("${oauth.client}")
    private String oauthClient;

    @Value("${oauth.secret}")
    private String oauthSecret;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices tokenService() {
        RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
        tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(oauthUrl + "/check_token");
        tokenService.setClientId(oauthClient);
        tokenService.setClientSecret(oauthSecret);
        return tokenService;
    }
}
```

Besides this, you may want to ignore Swagger-specific endpoints:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**");
    }
}
```

Just in case, this is the class I implemented for Swagger w/ OAuth2 authorization:

```
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final String BASE_PACKAGE = "com.somepackage.api";

    @Value("${oauth.url}")    // Make sure this is an external URL, i.e. accessible from Swagger UI
    private String oauthUrl;

    @Value("${swagger.scopes}")
    private String swaggerScopes;

    @Value("${swagger.urls}")
    private String swaggerUrls;    // Your v2/api-docs URL accessible from the UI

    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(BASE_PACKAGE))
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(securitySchema()))
            .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()));
    }

    private OAuth securitySchema() {
        List<AuthorizationScope> authorizationScopeList = new ArrayList<>();
        authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope(swaggerScopes, ""));

        List<GrantType> grantTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        GrantType creGrant = new ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant(oauthUrl + "/token");
        grantTypes.add(creGrant);

        return new OAuth("oauth2schema", authorizationScopeList, grantTypes);
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).forPaths(PathSelectors.ant(swaggerUrls)).build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        final AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = new AuthorizationScope(swaggerScopes, "");
        return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference("oauth2schema", authorizationScopes));
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Versions:

- springSecurityVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
- swaggerVersion = '2.8.0'
- springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'